# Convert Blob to List<int>

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

I'm using [protocol buffers in dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-protobuf) but having an issue due to the way data is received from the web socket connection.  Binary data is being received as a `Blob`, and the constructor for the protobuf message is expecting a `List<int>`.  How would I go about converting a `Blob` into a `List<int>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get this working by setting the `binaryType` property on the WebSocket object to `"arraybuffer"`.

`webSocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";`